# Select cell by td headers (using variable) and class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-table

**Problem**

I need to select a **td** by it's **header cat_11_18** (variable stored in obj.id) and **class column-percentage** (static), so that I can extract the text.

`<td headers="cat_11_18 row_50_18 percentage" class="level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-percentage">25 %</td>`

Currently trying:

```
$('td[headers*="' + obj.id '"].column-percentage').innerText;
```

---

**Demo Code Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  
  var cat = 'cat_11_18';
  
    alert(    $('td[headers*="' + cat + '"].column-percentage').innerText);
});
```

```html
<td headers="cat_11_17 row_45_18 percentage" class="level1 levelodd oddd1 baggb itemcenter  column-percentage">46 %</td>
<td headers="cat_11_17 row_45_18 average" class="level1 levelodd oddd1 baggb itemcenter  column-average">4</td>
<td headers="cat_11_17 row_45_18 feedback" class="level1 levelodd oddd1 baggb feedbacktext column-feedback">Great</td>
<br/>
<td headers="cat_11_18 row_50_18 percentage" class="level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-percentage">25 %</td>
<td headers="cat_11_18 row_50_18 average" class="level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-average">50</td>
<td headers="cat_11_18 row_50_18 feedback" class="level2 leveleven item b1b feedbacktext column-feedback">Rubbish</td>
```

---

**Background**

I am running through a table to create a series of graphs from the data. There are numerous categories identifiable by td header, and each graph has two series identifiable by class (student's results, average results). Categories can change between courses so I can't hard-code the solution.

It is successfully finding all the categories but I am struggling to select just the table cells appropriate for an individual category. It is working if I select just using class but this is inappropriate as all info will be mixed regardless of category.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, I'm missing your actual question. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `.html()`  not `innertext`  Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9qr05Lyz/)

```
<table border="1">

<td headers="cat_11_17 row_45_18 percentage" class="level1 levelodd oddd1 baggb itemcenter  column-percentage">46 %</td>
<td headers="cat_11_17 row_45_18 average" class="level1 levelodd oddd1 baggb itemcenter  column-average">4</td>
<td headers="cat_11_17 row_45_18 feedback" class="level1 levelodd oddd1 baggb feedbacktext column-feedback">Great</td>
<br/>
<td headers="cat_11_18" class="level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-percentage">25 %</td>
<td headers="cat_11_18 row_50_18 average" class="level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-average">50</td>
<td headers="cat_11_18 row_50_18 feedback" class="level2 leveleven item b1b feedbacktext column-feedback">Rubbish</td>

</table>
```

JS

```
$(function () {

  var cat = 'cat_11_18';

    alert(    $('td[headers*="' + cat + '"].column-percentage').html() );
});
```